# Resources error in android studio

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
above are  the error  i am getting when  i start the project...

Comment: post your above (topside) logcat of this error

Comment: Execute following command For mac/linux ./gradlew :app:processDebugResources --stacktrace for Windows use gradlew, and attach response into question

Comment: Can you post what [this, highlighted yellow](https://imgur.com/O8H7PlL) window has to say about this error?

Comment: As the previous commenters said, we need to see the logs with the errors. You can go to the Terminal window in Android Studio and run "gradlew clean assembleDebug" and paste here the output of that command.

Answer (score 0):

Options like

1) Select file from a menu, select Invalidate Caches/ Restart.

2) add this lines to your build.gradle

```
configurations {
 all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

3) Something is going wrong with your any XML file which contains a non-present key, check your XML files.